# How do I know my horse breed?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

Where do I find the breed information of the current horse I am riding in Red Dead Redemption? I have gone through stats and other information in settings page but, I could not find this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the only way to do so is to Google it, as the info isn't available in-game.

[Here's](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Horse_Breeds) the wiki entry on horse breeds.